# Problems running a Docker image built with an ARMv7 base image on a x86 desktop

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, x86, arm, qemu

I am trying to run a Docker image based on an [ARMv7](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/ubuntu/) container on a x86 computer. According to this [site](https://blog.hypriot.com/post/docker-intel-runs-arm-containers/), it is possible by running this container first.

```
docker run --rm --privileged hypriot/qemu-register
```

This command works on Mac OS X and on an Ubuntu 19 virtual machine (with a Windows 10 host). However, when I try to run on CentOS 7 and one of the [AWS A1 instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/a1/), I get the message `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"`. The CPU for the CentOS 7 is an Intel Core i7-8700K and AWS A1 is based on the [Graviton processor](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-instances-a1-powered-by-arm-based-aws-graviton-processors/).

Anyone know what I'm missing here?

The complaint on the AWS A1 instance is with installing [miniconda](http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh). I'm not sure if there is a way to say yes (to continue to install) since the `-b` flag already is supposed to get miniconda to install silently.

```
Step 6/11 : RUN /bin/bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/miniconda
 ---> Running in ab9b5fef6837
WARNING:
    Your processor does not appear to be an armv7l.  This software
    was sepicically build for the Raspberry Pi 2 running raspbian wheezy
    (or above).
    Are sure you want to continue the installation? [yes|no]
[no] >>> Aborting installation
```

Comment: An A1 instance uses an ARM CPU, not x86, so hopefully can run your code natively.  Only your i7-8700k (Coffee Lake) needs CPU emulation.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, you are right. But I should have clarified; I couldn't get the ARMv7 container to run on my desktop, so I spun up an AWS A1 instance and got the same message.

Comment: So what binary in your Docker image is causing that error?  What format exactly *does* it have, if you check with `readelf` or something.  Does A1 support 32-bit ARM natively, or is it only AArch64?

Comment: @PeterCordes I think there's 2 problems I'm conflating here. It's `miniconda` that is complaining (which was only compiled against the Raspberry Pi 2). The `uname -a` indeed does not show `armv7l` (instead, `aarch64`). So, I can let the AWS A1 problem slide (I guess I will have to contact Anaconda for that). However, the other problem with running on my x86 desktop (which is really what I'm after) remains.

Comment: Some AArch64 systems can run 32-bit processes as well.  (Like running a 32-bit x86 executable on an x86-64 system).  But perhaps not AWS A1 instances.  Does your `miniconda` executable run ok under `qemu-arm` directly, if you take Docker out of the picture?  (And not `qemu-system-arm` either, just single-process user-space emulation).  Or at least get past the "exec format error", and onto some error messages about missing dynamic libraries or something if you don't bother copying libraries.

Answer (score 4):

AWS A1 instances do support running Armv7 binaries.  Using the available Ubuntu 18.04 AMI for A1, run this on the command line:

```
cat /boot/config-4.15.0-1043-aws | grep "CONFIG_COMPAT=y"
```

If this succeeds, then the AMI and kernel have been built with support for running 32-bit executables on the 64-bit platform.  To test this capability, install using `apt-get install gcc:armhf libc6:armhf` to get a minimal 32-bit build environment, create an executable and execute `readelf -h` on it.  You should see the Machine listed as ARM, not AArch64.  Execution should also succeed.

Testing docker with armv7 images also works out of the box on the Ubuntu 18.04 AMI on A1.  I tested via `docker pull armhf/ubuntu:latest` and then entered interactive mode using bash and tried installing Miniconda3.  The problem does appear to be with the Miniconda install script linked above.  It tries this unconditionally on line 58:

```
if [[ `uname -m` != 'armv7l' ]]; then
    echo -n "WARNING:
    Your processor does not appear to be an armv7l.  This software
    was sepicically build for the Raspberry Pi 2 running raspbian wheezy
    (or above).
    Are sure you want to continue the installation? [yes|no]
[no] >>> "
    read ans
    if [[ ($ans != "yes") && ($ans != "Yes") && ($ans != "YES") &&
                ($ans != "y") && ($ans != "Y") ]]
    then
        echo "Aborting installation"
        exit 2
    fi
fi
```

Docker does not do any rewriting of what `uname -m` returns, it will see AArch64 on the A1 instance and it will trip up there.  Commenting this block out should get you going on the A1 instances.

For getting this to work on your x86 laptop, you will need to copy `qemu-arm-static` to the docker image to enable emulation.  I am not sure, but I would suspect that `uname` would still not return the proper machine-type Miniconda expects.